# (Javascript) Is there a way to define more than one property to a variable?

Tags: javascript, variables, global-variables

I am here, once again, to get help on my text based game.

Newest issue: Defining a variable to change the value of a global variable.

Let me get a snippet of what I mean.

So, this is causing me all kinds of issues, while trying to make a viable equip and shopping system.

I have one set of global variables defined as:

```
    var Armor = {
        ClothesName: "",
        HelmetName: "",
        BodyName: "",
        ArmName: "",
        WaistName: "",
        LegName: "",
        BootsName: ""
    }

    var Weapons = {
        SwordName: "",
        RightHand: "",
        ShieldName: "",
        LeftHand: "",
        BowName: "",
        ArrowName: "",
        NumberOfArrows: 0,
        StaffName: ""
    }
```

Then I have my armor set as such (this is the part that is the overall question):

```
    1.) There is no way I can see to plug the values into the global variable:
    var MangledRags = {
        Name: "Mangled Rags" //Name of the Armor.
        Defense: 0.25        //Boost to defense.
    }
```

or

```
    2.) The Armor.Name is pushed, but the hero.Defense is neglected:
    var MangledRags;
    MangledRags = 
        Armor.ClothesName = "Mangled Rags", //Name of the Armor pushed
        hero.Defense += 0.25;               //Increase to Hero's defense when worn.
```

I am using a function to try to push the information to the global variable:

```
    function equip() {
        if (Warrior == true) {
            Armor.ClothesName = MangledRags;
            document.getElementById("Armor.ClothesName").innerHTML = Armor.ClothesName;
            document.getElementById("hero.Defense").innerHTML = hero.Defense;
    }
```

Which is read here:

```
    if (Warrior == true) {
        $("<p>You equipped your armor warrior, and are on your way to town! Press <u><b>enter</b></u>.</p>").hide().insertBefore("#placeholder").fadeIn(1000); //Change the name of the warrior equipment
        isArmorOn = true;
        equip();
        currentarea = "Starter Town Gates";
        document.getElementById("currentarea").innerHTML = currentarea;
        return;
    }
```

Which in turn is read by the HTML text:

```
     <div id="main_attributes">
        <p>
           Name: <span id="hero.Name">0</span> &emsp; &emsp; Gender: <span id="hero.Gender">0</span><br />
           Class: <span id="hero.Class">0</span><br /><br />
           Health: <span id="hero.Health">0</span><br />
           Magic: <span id="hero.Magic">0</span><br />
           Attack Power: <span id="hero.Attack">0</span><br/>
           Defense: <span id="hero.Defense">0</span><br />
           Endurance: <span id="hero.Endurance">0</span><br />
           Current Location: <span id="currentarea">0</span>
        </p>
     </div>
     <div id="inv_left_left">
        <p>
           Head: <span id="Armor.HelmetName">0</span><br />
           Armor: <span id="Armor.BodyName">0</span><br />
           Hands: <span id="Armor.ArmName">0</span><br/>
           Waist: <span id="Armor.WaistName">0</span><br />
           Legs: <span id="Armor.LegName">0</span><br />
           Feet: <span id="Armor.BootsName">0</span><br />
        </p>
     </div>
```

I will create a separate question for my issues with the Shop system, if this question doesn't solve both problems for me.

I haven't found anything online similar to this question, so that is why I am posting here.

Comment: *I have one set of global variables* Well, first, you shouldn't have *any* global variables, but second, what you are showing is two **objects**.

Comment: True poor word choice, I meant to say that I have a set of global variables, which I see you are actually informing me are Objects. I can say that I am still many times over a novice, but as I am learning as I go. Eventually I will get to the point to where I can make many of them private, but at this stage, I am just trying to get things to work as I want. If you're telling me "Hey buddy, go check out how Objects work!" Fair enough.

Comment: I'm actually saying "Hey buddy, go check out why Globals are bad!". Seriously, starting with Globals because they are easier is not going to end well for you. It turns out, they aren't easier and you'll wind up coding yourself into a corner with them. Always start with the smallest scope possible and only expand it as the need arises.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a fair bit to unpack here and I think a lot of your problems could be solved by finishing a quick JavaScript tutorial since I think a lot of the principles (especially surrounding types) are eluding you.

`Armor` and `Weapons` are both *objects* and are instantiated with properties you defined on them in the first code snippet (`ClothesName`, `SwordName`, etc.). They do *nothing* beyond storing values assigned to the key names you define in your code.

I emphasize this because it seems that you wish to treat `Armor` and `Weapons` as *types*, specifically classes that will allow you to subclass them into instances of `Armor` and `Weapon` that have specific properties, such as with `MangledRags`. To directly address your problem, you can change the properties on the existing `Armor` global like so:

```
Armor.ClothesName = "Mangled Rags"
Armor.Defense = 0.25
```

You could even define a new object to store the mangled rags properties to avoid re-typing them:

```
var MangledRags = {
    ClothesName: "Mangled Rags",
    Defense: 0.25,
    // more properties here...
}

function wearMangledRags() {
    Armor.ClothesName = MangledRags.ClothesName;
    Armor.Defense = MangledRags.Defense;
    // etc.
}
```

This is bad code style. Not in a finger-waggy way, but because you will make life harder for yourself down the line with a lot of copy-pasting, code repetition, and potential for errors. In addition to brushing up on basic JS tenets, objects, and types, I'd recommend reading a [primer on classes](https://javascript.info/class).

You could treat `Armor` and `Weapons` as the types they ought to be and [use subclassing to define instances of those types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes). You will need ES6 features to use the `class` API, but it is possible to use them with vanilla JavaScript, albeit trickier and requires understanding of [prototypical inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

There are a few other errors in your code that fall along the same lines of misunderstanding the difference between a type and a value (e.g. `Warrior === true` will not work unless `Warrior` is a boolean value - you cannot evaluate class types this way, `Armor.ClothesName = MangledRags;` is assigning the object stored in the `MangledRags` variable into the `ClothesName` property of the `Armor` variable and I don't think that is what you want). I really recommend you brush up a little on basic JavaScript - there are a ton of free resources online! I think with a small step up in your understanding of the language you will be able to see the pitfalls of your code a little easier.

Feel free to message me here if you need more help breaking down anything here - I'd be happy to point you in the right direction! I don't think pointers like "globals are bad" are going to help solve your problem, but broad gains in your JavaScript understanding will make this program a breeze.